# I want `npm run build` generate the dist assets files in the static directory

Tags: npm, vue.js

In my `src/config/index.js`, the build settings is bellow:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  build: {
    env: require('./env'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: './',
    productionSourceMap: true,
    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  },
```

but after I `npm run build`, I get the results:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

shouldn't the assets file in the `static` directory? where is the error of config?

I want the dist directory like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

my `webpack.prod.config.js` default code is bellow:

```
......
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: '/index.html',
      template: './src/template/index.ejs',
      inject: false
    })
  ]
});
```

the `filename: '/index.html',` so, the index.html is in the above of dist directory.

Comment: Are you sure this file is even being recognized by webpack-cli? its a non standard name, not in the root project directory. Maybe use something like webpack.config.js as that's the default (for good reason)